# Why go module pseudo version have a specific version?

Tags: go, version, go-modules

I have a go.mod looks like

```
require(
   ...
   github.com/google/wire v0.3.1-0.20190716160000-66f78fc84606
   ...
)
```

Based on my understanding, if a package looks like that (yyyymmddMMSS-commit_id), which version should be `v0.0.0` but not `v0.3.1` as this example.

Could someone guide me how should I explain this? Does go mod ignore the `v0.3.1-` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the result of `go get`'ing a specific commit that exists in the tree *after* a semantic version tag:

`go get github.com/google/wire@66f78fc84606`

Pseudo versions are used not only when there is no version tag.
As the official documentation about [pseudo versions](https://golang.org/ref/mod#tmp_4) shows:

> Pseudo-versions may refer to revisions for which no semantic version tags are available. They may be used to test commits before creating version tags, for example, on a development branch.
>
> ...
>
> vX.Y.(Z+1)-0.yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefabcdef is used when the base version is a release version like vX.Y.Z.

In this case, the repository does have semantic version tags. The base version here is [`v0.3.0`](https://github.com/google/wire/releases/tag/v0.3.0), and by getting a specific commit (`66f78fc84606`) that exists after `v0.3.0` and before the next one `v0.4.0`, you end up with:

`github.com/google/wire v0.3.1-0.20190716160000-66f78fc84606`

Answer (score 2):

In fact there are 3 acceptable forms of pseudo-version:

1. **vX.0.0-yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefxyz**.
   *when no earlier versioned commit with an appropriate major version before target commit*
2. **vX.Y.Z-pre.0.yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefxyz**
   *when most recent versioned commit before the target commit is vX.Y.Z-pre*
3. **vX.Y.(Z+1)-0.yyyymmddhhmmss-abcdefxyz**
   *when most recent versioned commit before the target commit is vX.Y.Z*

Some more details about **Managing Go Module Pseudo-Versions**:
https://hackernoon.com/managing-go-module-pseudo-versions-in-go-113-412h30lw